# Moving Elements in DOM for Responsive Web Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

### A Brief Explanation

I have created a responsive website that effectively has three views (desktop,tablet,mobile). Most of the design is changed via CSS using media queries (as it should be for responsive websites). However, part of the design is too complex to simply be manipulated via CSS as the HTML actually needs to be moved around the DOM. I know this doesn't sound too great but I cannot see how else I am meant to replicate this design without moving certain elements within my HTML.

So, with the above in mind, I now plan to write a function that creates custom events for each of the different ‘responsive views’. When each event is fired (in sync with the CSS media queries), it will execute some Javascript to move/animate any elements that cannot be manipulated enough using CSS.

### My Question

Is this the best method to go about doing this? If, not, what other options do I have? Are there any existing libraries that I could look at and learn from?

***My actual question is; What is the best method of moving elements in the DOM for responsive web design?***

### Further Explanation

If the above wasn’t clear, then read the following:

Consider these three different views:

[image: Responsive Views]

Now consider the code for the first two views:

**Desktop**

```
<div id="some_container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    <nav>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <!-- The rest of the content -->
</div>
```

**Tablet**

```
<div id="some_container">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    <nav>
    <!-- The rest of the content -->
</div>
```

***Notice the `nav` tag has been moved below the `p` tag...***

Comment: I'd just add either the nav or the the text twice, then display only the one you want, depending on media queries.

Comment: @Cerbrus that will increase load time..... and ideally not good idea...

Comment: @C-link By very, very, very little.

Comment: @C-link: The difference in load time is very insignificant. It would be similar to a page having a paragraph of text extra. _Maybe_ it's an extra 2kB to load.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you target different browsers' screen and put many times in different places then what happens...?

Comment: @C-link: I'm having trouble comprehending your question. _"put many times in different places"_?

Comment: I've always used @Cerbrus technique and it works well for me. No added JS needed and minimal at best added load time, you won't even notice the difference, not even on dial up...

Comment: if there's no jQuery library loaded to build the whole website, then it'd be a nice solution.

Comment: Try not moving things around the DOM. It means that you have to rebind any mouse events, and moving around takes an equally long time as well (especially if you're using jQuery to do it - talking from experience). If at all possible, redesign your site so that things can be moved around with media queries only. This means that resizing a page is quicker as well (still talking from experience)

Comment: I can't believe that this is functionally impossible. The only real answers are hacks. How broken is the DOM? What a joke!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="some_container">
    <nav id="n1">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <nav id="n2">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

You will only need the following css:

```
#n1{
    display:none;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 600px) {
    #n1{
        display:block;
    }
    #n2{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t2DAz/)**

This basically toggles which of the two navigation sections you see, depending on the screen size. It has the disadvantage of duplicated html in your source (the difference in the amount of data is really negligible), but you won't need JavaScript to get the effect, and JS disabled devices will only show one `ul`.

The great thing about this way is that it's very scale-able. Need this "effect" on a different page? You'll only have to edit [u]that[/u] page. No messing around with JavaScript, hard-coding new classes / cases.

Comment: I did consider this method but I just don't like the idea of having repetitive HTML...

Comment: @BenCarey: How many characters is that nav? I'm absolutely certain the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: That is very true and fair, but this is just an example. The site has several elements that need to be moved around, I am just not that confident it is the best method... Not to mention it makes the code harder, albeit it very little, to maintain

Comment: In all honesty, the reason I did not originally use this method was because I did not want duplicate code, and I felt it wasn't the most effective solution. But, having now looked at it further I feel it may be the better solution. Simply because it load the pages as it is meant to look, it does not need to wait for jQuery to load to move the elements, I can handle the animations within the CSS, it doesn't affect the load time and it doesn't make the code *much* harder to maintain. And lastly, I have been advised by someone with a rep of 13k so I feel inclined to trust what you say :-)

Comment: @BenCarey: To be fair, it's only 12.9k ;-) I thank you for your recognition, though. The JS option works too, but I think it may have some drawbacks, like you summed up, indeed.

Comment: but duplicated content is super bad for SEO

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)/[`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to move the elements based on the page size:

```
$(window).resize(){
    resize();
}

$(document).ready(){
    resize();
}

function resize(){
    if($(window).width() < 480)
    {
        //Mobile
        $("#some_container nav").insertAfter("#some_container p");
    }
    else if($(window).width() < 800)
    {
        //Tablet
        $("#some_container nav").insertAfter("#some_container p");
    }
    else
    {
        //Desktop
        //Leave original layout
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very basic version of the function I plan to write. The issues occur when I want to go from desktop->mobile (skipping tablet) etc...

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: To be honest, there is no issue, I can very easily write this code. I just want to be sure that this is the best method for achieving what I have explained.

Comment: **Best** is subjective. I can only offer you a good, working solution.

Comment: The reason it is more complicated than your above example is the fact that I want my function to be dynamic so I can add as many views as the client wants and the function will create custom events for each view. I can do this, so no need to help me write the code. I just wanted to hear other peoples views before I started on the function :-)

Comment: @BenCarey: Just to provide an example for my answer: Look at the amound of JavaScript this requires. Then compare that with the amount of (dynamically generated) html my suggestion would add.
Load times aren't different, for these solutions.

Comment: But then of course, you can use variable selectors (especially relative functions like `.closest()`, `.siblings()`, `.parent()`, etc.) and loops to easily apply the same code in multiple places. It just depends on which path **you** want to walk down. Depending on the amount of elements you end up having to move, if done properly, a JS solution will probably require the least amount of work.

Comment: Of course, yes. Just wondering: won't this flash the "original" layout, before the element gets moved on `doc.ready`, on smaller screens? I disagree with the "amount of work", though. My suggestion merely requires a copy of the navigation (generation) code, a wrapper with a `small` or `large` class, for example, and the css can be reused anywhere. Using this functionality on a new page only requires the user to edit that page.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not necessarily. It depends on the performance of the user's system. It all relies on the time when the JS is loaded into the page, however, at worst it may be a single frame before the content is moved. For the average internet connection, there will be no issue at all. As far as the amount of work, the layout has to be surveyed for each and every instance of the problem. It is about the same, but in the long run, the JS solution will allow him to simply put a class or an attribute on the element he wants to move and that is it. JS allows a lot more flexibility.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, most websites use JS in some form, and a very high amount use jQuery, so the content would be loaded anyway.

Comment: So, what if I have 2 different elements on the same page, that I want to move to different places? Like: `a B c d e f G h i --> a c B d e f h G i`

Comment: I would set a class on a and G and do `$(".class").each(function(){$(this).insertAfter($(this).next());});`

Comment: And if the target isn't necessarily the `next()` element, but differs from case to case basis? (You'll need a `.target` class) I'm trying to get a point across: Yes, this can be done with JS, but it's a lot easier to just place the elements where you want them, and show them depending on the media query

Comment: The solution would need to account for all cases, but so what? The same applies to a CSS solution. He would have to explicitly place the copy exactly where he wants it in the source. From what it looks like, there will be a limited number of cases, so the "what if he has over 9000 different cases?" is irrelevant. That'd be ridiculous.

Comment: My point is that the css solution doesn't care where the elements are placed. It works for __all__ cases. JavaScript has to be modified for different cases, or has to have checks built in. You may even need to add `target` divs, which is getting very close to what my solution is doing.

Comment: As I said earlier. The solutions are very similar. The decision belongs to that of whom is creating the page. Neither solution is **better** than the other; it just depends on preference and understanding.

Comment: They're not similar at all. One solution doesn't touch css, and the other is 90% css.

Comment: Tomato, tomahto. It's all opinions from here on out.

Comment: More like "plane, submarine". They both result in you being moved from point A to point B, but do so in a completely different manner.

Comment: $(window).resize(){
    resize();
}
its Wrong.
It should be 
$(window).resize(function(){
 resize()
});

Comment: also, this duplicates the items rather than moving them to another place

Answer (score 6):

The enquire.js library solves this problem by allowing you to fire JS functions in response to CSS media queries. So you could run your detach() and append() logic according to different screen sizes. It is lightweight to boot.

See: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

Comment: looks like it might not be getting updates anymore

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods like [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
//check for the window width
if($(window).width() < 700){
  //append to the p  
  $('#some_container nav').appendTo('#some_container p');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am aware of how to append the DOM and move elements around based on window size, what I would like to know is whether it is the best method for achieving this in sync with the CSS media queries?

Comment: with css media query you cannot move the elements as @Cerbus said you have to do like that....

Comment: if you mean media query with js that's good. just search about that you'll find a lot of results on that....

Answer (score 2):

Creating duplicate content to solve responsive design challenges is not a best practice. It makes the markup harder to maintain (especially when another developer takes over the project and doesn't realize it has to be updated in more than one location), it increases file size (if file size wasn't important, we wouldn't minify our CSS/JS or GZIP our HTML), and assistive technologies and other web agents that don't take CSS into account see it as repeated content.

It's just messy, and I don't see how anyone would consider it a best practice.

While JavaScript isn't ideal either, I see no issue if it is used as a form of progressive enhancement. I recently found myself using it often enough that I created a jQuery plugin for it: https://github.com/thomashigginbotham/responsive-dom

Sample usage:

```
var $mainNav = $('.main-nav');

$mainNav.responsiveDom({
    appendTo: '.sidebar',
    mediaQuery: '(min-width: 600px)'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

These days, to change the position of particular elements in a design, you do not need to move them in the DOM, you just need to change their display order using the CSS order property:

So given the following HTML structure:

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <!-- The rest of the content -->
</div>
```

as long as your container is a flex element, you can manipulate the display order of its children (in a media query if you wish) by giving one or more of them an order property. This has a zero-based value, so '1' will placed it second in the order:

```css
#container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 400px)
{
  nav
  {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

On a screen smaller than 401px, you would see this:

Some text

- Item 1
- Item 2

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make javascript, use grid technique.

```
<div class="main_container">
    <nav class="grid_nav">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    <nav>
    <div class="grid_text">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- The rest of the content -->
</div>
```

```
.main_container{
  display: grid;
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) { //mobile
    grid-template-rows:    1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "gridnav"
                         "gridtext";
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {//web
    grid-template-rows:    1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "gridtext"
                         "gridnav";
  }
}

.grid_nav{
  grid-area: gridnav;
}
.grid_text{
  grid-area: gridtext;
}
```

But is only when the movements are inside of the "main_container"

regards...

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a jQuery plugin which does exactly this, have a look [here](http://www.easyresponsive.com/hopscotch.htm).  Basically it automatically builds a series of layouts in terms of rows and columns, which are then used for the different views as you show above

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this exact thing right now with navigation that I need to move into the header for desktop and just below the header for a hamburger menu on mobile. I have an event listener on the window being resized that calls a function that checks screen size and passes it to my toggleNavigation function. I have this separate because I have a few other functions aside from that that get called in the checkBreakPoint that are not listed. Then to make sure that it is not constantly moving my dom or re-appending it I first check what parent container it is in and only move it if it is not in the one I expect for that screensize. My project requires that it not have any external dependencies so this is just done in plain Javascript and then I use media queries to style the elements based on screen size.

```
var mainNav = document.getElementById('rww_main_nav'); //element I want to move
var tieredHeader = document.getElementById('rww_tiered_header'); //where it should be on mobile
var branding = document.getElementById('rww_branding'); //where it should be on desktop

window.addEventListener("resize", checkBreakPoint);

function checkBreakPoint() {
        //width of viewport
        var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        toggleNavLocation(w);
}

function toggleNavLocation(screensize) {
    if (screensize > 999) {
        if (mainNav.parentElement.id === 'rww_tiered_header') {
            branding.appendChild(mainNav);
        }
    } else {
        if (mainNav.parentElement.id === 'rww_branding') {
            tieredHeader.appendChild(mainNav);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may introduce a whole new set of problems, but could you use position: absolute on the elements set to move, and have them reposition around the page based on the size of the screen?